# Converting the data in year month day hour and minutes to date in R

Tags: r

I am trying to convert the date as factor to date using “as.date” function in R. I have the date in the following format

```
2008-01-01 02:30
```

I tried to use the following command :

```
as.Date(mydata$Date, format="%y-%m-%d  %h:%mm")
```

Can somebody help me with this ? I was able to convert the format with no hour but getting difficulty with hour included.

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your format string is incorrect :

```
R> strptime("2008-01-01 02:30", format="%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M")
# [1] "2008-01-01 02:30:00"
```

See `?strptime` for the detailed values you can use to define a format.

Also note that as your string is in a standard format, you can also use directly `as.POSIXlt` :

```
R> as.POSIXlt("2008-01-01 02:30")
# [1] "2008-01-01 02:30:00"
```

Comment: +1 Perhaps should also mention that `as.Date` will only yield a date, not also the time.

Comment: @ juba, thank you so much for your answer. Actually I had tried using POSIXlt but I had format wrong on that one too.